# Swift search string for any number?

Tags: string, swift

I'm trying to get my app to identify dates. I have an array of strings that it searches through. I'm using rangeOfString() to search for a "/", which is in the dates. However, some areas in the strings have backslashes that aren't part of dates, and that messes up the search. Can I get it to search for a backslash immediately followed by a number. In PHP, it would be preg_match("///[0-9]/"), but how is it done with Swift?

Comment: I guess you're looking for `NSRegularExpression`.

Comment: What's that and how can I use it?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/index.html

Answer (score 3):

If you need to match any date in your string you can use NSDataDetector - NSRegularExpression subclass designed to detect some specific data:

Swift version:

```
var error : NSError?

if let detector = NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingType.Date.rawValue, error: &error) {
  let testString = "Today date is 15/11/2014!! Yesterday was 15-11-2014"

  let matches = detector.matchesInString(testString, options: .allZeros, range: NSMakeRange(0, countElements(testString))) as [NSTextCheckingResult]

  for match:NSTextCheckingResult in matches {
    println(match.date, match.range)
  }
}
```

Obj-c version:

```
NSDataDetector* detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeDate
                                                             error:NULL];
NSString* testString = @"Today date is 15/11/2014!! Yesterday was 14-11-2014";
NSArray* matches = [detector matchesInString:testString
                                     options:0
                                       range:NSMakeRange(0, testString.length)];
// Will match 2 date occurences
for (NSTextCheckingResult* match in matches) {
  NSLog(@"%@ in %@", match.date, NSStringFromRange(match.range));
}
```

Comment: Sorry, missed swift part of the question. Added swift sample code to the answer